# Vue, Laravel - Apexchart piechart

Tags: laravel, vue.js, apexcharts

I am having trouble to pass the data `11` and `33` to a format of `[11, 33]` to the `series` of piechart. Here is my current code.

**Template:**

```
<div id="chart">
  <apexchart type="pie" width="380" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexchart>
</div>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      series: [],
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            width: 380,
            type: 'pie',
          },
          labels: ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C', 'Team D', 'Team E'],
        }
    }),

    methods: {
      kpiProgress () {
        axios.get('/api/employee-kpi-progress', {
          params: { employee_id: this.$store.state.authUser.employee_id }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.series = response.data.employee_objectivekpa
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
  public function kpiProgress(Request $request) {
    $get = EmployeeObjective::with('employeeObjectivekpa:employee_objective_id,kpi_progress')
    ->where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
    ->first();
    return response()->json($get);
  }
```

This is the data I'm currently having in the `response.data`. How do turn this into an array for the `series`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggeting to use Eloquent's `pluck` method

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck

```
public function kpiProgress(Request $request) {
   return EmployeeObjective::with('employeeObjectivekpa:employee_objective_id,kpi_progress')
    ->where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
    ->first()->pluck('kpi_progress');

}
```

or in JavaScript:

```
const myarray = response.data.map((item) -> {
      return item.kpi_progress;
})
```

Comment: It's inside the `employee_objectivekpa` so I really can't use pluck after `first()->`

Comment: What about the JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 0):

It now works, I'll share the answer to everyone.

**Template**

```
 kpiProgress () {
        axios.get('/api/employee-kpi-progress', {
          params: { employee_id: this.$store.state.authUser.employee_id }
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.series = response.data
          console.log(response.data)
          })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      },
```

**Controller**

```
public function kpiProgress(Request $request) {
    $get = EmployeeObjective::with('employeeObjectivekpa:employee_objective_id,kpi_progress')
    ->where('employee_id', $request->employee_id)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('employeeObjectivekpa')
    ->flatten()
    ->pluck('kpi_progress')
    ->toArray();

    return response()->json($get);
  }
```